# Я хочу сделать сохранение текста после нажимания на кнопку и потом использовать этот текст как кнопку

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, app

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore










sm = ScreenManager()
Window.size = (375, 700)
Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)

Builder.load_string("""
#: import Window kivy.core.window.Window
<HomeScreen>:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'
        padding: 40
        Button:
            background_normal: '12.png'
            size_hint: [.3, .15]
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'add'
<AddScreen>:
    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x: False
        do_scroll_y: True
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y:None
            height:Window.height * 1.5
            orientation: 'vertical'
            spacing: 20
            padding: 20
            Button:
                id: button_next
                text: '>'

            Button:
                id: button_one
                text: 'PRESS'
                on_press: root.new()

            Button:
                id: button_2
                on_press: root.new1()
                text: 'biceps'
            Button:
                id: button_3
                text: 'TRICEPS'
                on_press: root.new2()
            Button:
                id: button_4
                on_press: root.new3()
                text: 'quatrocipeps'
            Button:
                text: 'lashka'
                id: button_5
                on_press: root.new4()

            Button:
                id: button_6
                on_press: root.new5()

                text: 'kakashka'
            Button:
                id: button_7
                on_press: root.new6()

                text: 'kakashka'
            Button:
                id: button_8
                on_press: root.new7()

                text: 'kakashka'
            Button:
                id: button_9
                on_press: root.new8()

                text: 'kakashka'
            Button:
                text: '...'
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'custom'

<CustomScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 40
        Label:
            color: 150, 127, 115, 0.86
            text: 'CUSTOM:'
            font_size: 125
            bold: True
            font_name: 'Arial'
        TextInput:
            font_size: 40

        Button:
            id: button_save
            text: 'Save'

            on_press: root.store()



    """)








#place for text input and saving it to AddScreen directory
class CustomScreen(Screen):
    pass












class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class AddScreen(Screen):
    def new(self):
        self.ids['button_one'].background_color = 0, 0, 255, 0.5
    def new1(self):
        self.ids['button_2'].background_color = 0, 0, 255, 0.5
    def new2(self):
        self.ids['button_3'].background_color = 0, 0, 255, 0.5
    def new3(self):
        self.ids['button_4'].background_color = 0, 0, 255, 0.5
    def new4(self):
        self.ids['button_5'].background_color = 0, 0, 255, 0.5
    def new5(self):
        self.ids['button_6'].background_color = 0, 0, 255, 0.5

    def new6(self):
        self.ids['button_7'].background_color = 0, 0, 255, 0.5

    def new7(self):
        self.ids['button_8'].background_color = 0, 0, 255, 0.5

    def new8(self):
        self.ids['button_9'].background_color = 0, 0, 255, 0.5



sm.add_widget(HomeScreen(name='HOME'))
sm.add_widget(AddScreen(name='add'))
sm.add_widget(CustomScreen(name='custom'))

class app(App):
    def build(self):

        return sm




if __name__=='__main__':
    app().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял добавлять новую кнопку нужно туда, где у вас куча других кнопок.
Я в кнопке на стартовом экране написал свой текст так как у меня нет той картинки, что у вас.

Вот еще некоторые замечания:
В CustomScreen нет объекта store - добавляю.

Создание экранов лучше, все же, делать в билде.

В CustomScreen не так - color: (150, 127, 115, 0.86),
а вот так - color: (0.58, 0.49, 0.45, 0.86) - писать цвета в процентах

То место куда будем добавлять новую кнопку обзываем id:box

Одно серьезное замечание - у вас каждая кнопка получает свой метод изменения цвета. Это не правильно, как по мне, вот в этих местах - on_press: root.new(), ну и так далее. Проще написать on_press:root.change_color(self)

А в классе AddScreen написать метод change_color()
которая будет менять цвет всем новым кнопкам. Подробнее опишу ниже в коде.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore


Window.size = (375, 700)
Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)

Builder.load_string("""
#: import Window kivy.core.window.Window
<HomeScreen>:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'
        padding: 40
        Button:
            size_hint: [.3, .15]
            text:'next'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'add'

<AddScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        ScrollView:
            do_scroll_x: False
            do_scroll_y: True
            BoxLayout:
                id:box
                size_hint_y:None
                height:Window.height * 1.5
                orientation: 'vertical'
                spacing: 20
                padding: 20
                Button:
                    id: button_next
                    text: '>'

                Button:
                    id: button_one
                    text: 'PRESS'
                    on_press: root.new()

                Button:
                    id: button_2
                    on_press: root.new1()
                    text: 'biceps'
                Button:
                    id: button_3
                    text: 'TRICEPS'
                    on_press: root.new2()
                Button:
                    id: button_4
                    on_press: root.new3()
                    text: 'quatrocipeps'
                Button:
                    text: 'lashka'
                    id: button_5
                    on_press: root.new4()

                Button:
                    id: button_6
                    on_press: root.new5()

                    text: 'kakashka'
                Button:
                    id: button_7
                    on_press: root.new6()

                    text: 'kakashka'
                Button:
                    id: button_8
                    on_press: root.new7()

                    text: 'kakashka'
                Button:
                    id: button_9
                    on_press: root.new8()

                    text: 'kakashka'
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y:None
            height:Window.height*0.1
            padding:20,0,20,0
            Button:
                text: '...'
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'custom'

<CustomScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 40
        Label:
            color: (0.58, 0.49, 0.45, 0.86)
            text: 'CUSTOM:'
            font_size: 125
            bold: True
        TextInput:
            id:input
            font_size: 40
            text:''
        Button:
            text: 'Save'

            on_press: root.store(input.text)


<MyButton>:
    text:''
    on_press:root.on_press()
    """)

class MyButton(Button):
    #Создаем свою кнопку которая будет передавать ссылку на себя в качестве аргумента
    def __init__(self,my_parent,**kwargs):
        self.my_parent=my_parent
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_press(self):
        self.my_parent.change_color(self)#передача ссылки на себя экземпляру my_parent

#place for text input and saving it to AddScreen directory
class CustomScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self,add,**kwargs):
        self.add=add#Это нужно чтобы иметь доступ к его переменным и методам
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def store(self,txt):
        self.add.ids.box.add_widget(MyButton(text=txt,my_parent=self.add))#кидаем по айдишнику в конец списка всех кнопок кнопку с введенным названием
        #и передаем ссылку на класс в котором будем производить изменения новосозданной кнопки.
        self.manager.current='add'#переключаемся на экран кнопок


class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass


class AddScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def new(self):
        self.ids['button_one'].background_color = 0, 0, 255, 0.5
    def new1(self):
        self.ids['button_2'].background_color = 0, 0, 255, 0.5
    def new2(self):
        self.ids['button_3'].background_color = 0, 0, 255, 0.5
    def new3(self):
        self.ids['button_4'].background_color = 0, 0, 255, 0.5
    def new4(self):
        self.ids['button_5'].background_color = 0, 0, 255, 0.5
    def new5(self):
        self.ids['button_6'].background_color = 0, 0, 255, 0.5

    def new6(self):
        self.ids['button_7'].background_color = 0, 0, 255, 0.5

    def new7(self):
        self.ids['button_8'].background_color = 0, 0, 255, 0.5

    def new8(self):
        self.ids['button_9'].background_color = 0, 0, 255, 0.5

    def change_color(self,instance):# instance -это ссылка на кнопку которую я передавал ранее.
        instance.background_color=(0,0,1,0.5)


class app(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(HomeScreen(name='HOME'))
        self.add=AddScreen(name='add')#создаю экемпляр чтобы потом передать его как параметр
        sm.add_widget(self.add)
        sm.add_widget(CustomScreen(add=self.add,name='custom'))#передаю экземпляр self.add
        return sm


if __name__=='__main__':
    app().run()
```

Comment: Спасибо АЛЕКСЕЙ!!!